# Spring mvc converting json response links to https

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i have a spring mvc REST service that returns a json response (gson serialized) . the response contains nodes with a specific link 
example :

```
{ link : "http://www.test.com"}
```

when i access the service using http it's fine , but when accessing the service through https the links in the result are converted to https

```
{ link : "https://www.test.com"}
```

any idea?

Full example:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test",method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.OPTIONS}, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public String getTest(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model, HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    String test = "{ link : \"http://www.test.com\"}";
    return test;
}
```

Comment: Maybe some more information? spring version, the spring mvc controller code for the REST service. Type&version of container you're using.

Comment: Spring mvc 3.1 , and i'm using JacksonJson. I have an object and i'm using toJSON() on my object

Comment: using these in the header :@RequestMapping(value ="/test",method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.OPTIONS},
   produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
 @ResponseBody

Comment: Not using Websphere? And what code is producing the value of the link?

Comment: I am using jboss,the following response is converted to https when i access it from https Full example:

 @RequestMapping(value = "/test",method = {RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.OPTIONS}, produces = "application/json;charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseBody
public String getTest(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model, HttpServletRequest request,   HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    String test = "{ link : \"http://www.test.com\"}";
    return test;
}

Comment: I believer there is some CORS issue here.

Comment: I am not accessing the service from a different domain but directly

Comment: Then ditch the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, I believe its only for dealing with CORS. Also I see a mismatch between your comment and the code in the question regarding the value of the link property.

Comment: I applied your suggestion and removed the CORS header, that last posted code is the actual one. (Full example) . It's really weird , i have removed all the dependencies and no idea why spring mvc is converting my links

Comment: I rechecked it and it seems the issue is not from spring mvc . i am suspecting the browser

Comment: Can you use HttpClient? also what happens if you modify 'link' to lets say "address"? If it were Websphere I'd say take a look at Webspshere configuration, not sure if this is also applicable to jboss.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue before and after searching for a full day I could not find a solution. So what I did was a work around to remove the protocol from the link url in the json response before returning it.

Answer (score 0):

(My comment was in edit mode too long).
I believe there is some CORS issue here. To the best of my knowledge (but you may want to double check with google):  Access-Control-Allow-Origin should only be used in a preflight request (with OPTIONS). After the browser has received this, it (the browser) is allowed to do a GET request and you can server whatever you want. I'm not sure what happens if you combine the 2 requests in one method, and serve a link back.